# ;[discord.js] How to check author id of a message id equal bot id or not

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, replit

This is my code

```js
const botID = '986945043849945088'
let msgID = await message.channel.messages.fetch(args[0]).catch(() => undefined);
      if (msgID.includes(botID)) return message.reply(`This message does not belong to <@${client.user.id}>`)      
      if (msgID === undefined) {
        return message.reply('Wrong Message ID!')      
      } else {
        await msgID.edit(args[1]).then(() => message.delete())
```

This is error:

> TypeError: msgID.includes is not a function at Object.exports.callback (/home/runner/J-Bot/Commands/edit.js:30:17)

Comment: If I edit a message dose not belong to bot this is error:
`DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/J-V-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/J-V-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async MessageManager.edit (/home/runner/J-V-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:132:15)`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msgID is a `message`. So there's no `includes` function.
Just easily do.

```
const botID = '986945043849945088'
let msgID = await message.channel.messages.fetch(args[0]).catch(() => undefined);
      if (msgID.author.id != botID) return message.reply(`This message does not belong to <@${client.user.id}>`)      
      if (msgID === undefined) {
        return message.reply('Wrong Message ID!')      
      } else {
        await msgID.edit(args[1]).then(() => message.delete())
```